# try to devide two data tables recives NaN in some positions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan, divide

created this code for dividing 2 stock prices in order to pair trade using 2 data frames as shown below

```
import yfinance as yf
ticker_1, ticker_2 = 'SENEA', 'SENEB'
start_date = "2021-01-01"
interval = "1d"
data1 = yf.download(ticker_1, start=start_date, interval=interval)
data2 = yf.download(ticker_2, start=start_date, interval=interval)
print(data1)
print(data2)
data = data1/data2.squeeze()
print(data)
```

[results came up like this :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HDNXg.png)

anyone knows why some values recive NaN ?
thankyou

Comment: Hi @shade1234 - welcome to StackOverflow! When asking or answering a question on this site, please post code and data as formatted text blocks - [don't upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Images can't be searched, aren't readable by people with visual impairments, and the links can be corrupted or break. See this guide on [how to ask a good question](/help/how-to-ask). Can you edit your question to include the data?

Answer (score 0):

They don't have same dimensions,

try`np.shape(data1)` and `np.shape(data2)` to see for yourself.

Reproduced here with random points

```
pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(185,6))/pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(122,6))
```